# Missing tag wiki update from Stack Overflow

Tags: support, tag-wiki

On Stack Overflow, a proposed tag wiki update for [mootools](/questions/tagged/mootools) from yesterday seems to have been lost. Does it mean it has been "peer rejected" and if so, why / where has the markdown gone? Can we get notified if it gets removed or whatnot?

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mootools/info in the edit history, it would have gone in as Revision 20.

As it happens, nobody else that's active in the MooTools community bothers updating it so when something like new books and reviews come out, they should be included in the wiki. Not a single member of the MooTools core team has enough Stack Overflow reputation points to upvote a wiki edit, which is a bit of a shame.

Comment: Are you talking about a tag wiki update that your *suggested* or one that you *approved*?

Comment: There is a revision 19 from yesterday. Is that it?

Comment: no - a new edit I suggested after the other update by @eerne which improved on it and added a new book etc.